# Checking for non-zero values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6

I am in the process of writing a program that connects to a Cisco switch or router and then examines the output of a 'show int '.  I then process/parse the data to the point where I have a dictionary of twenty-one 
key/value pairs.  All values are integers.  It is working exactly as I want
up to this point.

I am having some trouble visualizing what I want to do next and I was hoping I could get some ideas and/or guidance.

What I want to do is this:

Check each value.  If ALL values are zero, then skip that dictionary.
  If ANY single value is non-zero (it will be a positive integer if it is not
  zero), then I want to save to a file the entire dictionary.

Each iteration of my program creates a dictionary representing data from a switch or router port.

Since I want the entire dictionary (all twenty-one key/value pairs) if even a single value is non-zero, I wasn't sure if adding all of the values and then 
checking if the sum is > 0 was the best option.

I could potentially be checking thousands of switch ports.

It seems to me that 'best' would be to start checking values and as soon as I hit a non-zero value then I want to save the entire dictionary and proceed to the next one (looping through the ports on a switch, for example), but I am just not sure of how to accomplish that.

I would appreciate some ideas or examples on how to best accomplish this task.

Oh, and I hesitate to use the word 'best'.  Since I will be processing thousands of ports what I don't want is an inefficient approach, which is why
I am hesitating to simply add up all of the values.

I am just not sure how to put into code:  "as soon as I see a single non-zero
value, save off the entire dictionary and proceed to the next one".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a direct translation of the request, working from the parts you've already done and incorporating the [*any()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any) function applied to the [*values*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) of the dictionary.

```
# I am in the process of writing a program that connects to a Cisco switch or
# router and then examines the output of a 'show int '. I then process\parse the
# data to the point where I have a dictionary of twenty-one key\value pairs.
# All values are integers.
for device in devices:
    s = run_show_interfaces(device)
    d = preprocess_parse(s)

    # Check each value. If ALL values are zero, then skip that dictionary. If ANY
    # single value is non-zero (it will be a positive integer if it is not zero),
    # then I want to save to a file the entire dictionary.
    if any(d.values()):
        filename = os.path.join(device, '.txt')
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(d, f)
```

FYI, the *any()* function has an early-out and will stop looking as soon as it finds a non-zero value.  In Python 3, *values()* returns a view of the data so it doesn't copy all of information.  In Python 2, use [*viewvalues()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewvalues) to achieve the same effect.  Taken together, this will give you great preformance.

Answer (score 0):

if all non-zero keys have the same value, you can just do dict.get(x), if x is not in the dictionary, it will return none.

otherwise:

```
    for value in dict.values():
      if value != 0:
        return true
    return false
```

you may also want to do a dict.get(0) first in the case all values are non-zero.